# Simulating Proportional Hazards Weibull model with 2 binary variables, incorrect estimation?

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution, proportional-hazards

I am simulating survival times from a `Weibull(5,3)`, and I also simulate 2 spurious binary covariates. When I fit a proportional hazards model with Weibull baseline, I would expect the estimators of the regression parameters associated to the binary covariates to be close to zero, but this is not the case:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(survival)
library(flexsurv)

n <- 10000
# Covariates
set.seed(123)
x <- cbind(rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = 0.5),rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = 0.5))
cens <- 5
# Survival times
set.seed(123)
sim <- rweibull(n, scale = 5, shape = 3)
status <- ifelse(sim < cens, 1, 0)
sim <- ifelse(sim < cens, sim, cens)

hist(sim)
mean(status)


# Estimated parameters


phreg(Surv(sim, status) ~ x[,1] + x[,2],
      dist = "weibull")
```

**Results:**

```
Call:
phreg(formula = Surv(sim, status) ~ x[, 1] + x[, 2], dist = "weibull")

Covariate          W.mean      Coef Exp(Coef)  se(Coef)    Wald p
x[, 1]              0.386     2.960    19.298     0.033     0.000 
x[, 2]              0.492    -0.013     0.987     0.025     0.614 

log(scale)                    1.850               0.006     0.000 
log(shape)                    1.609               0.011     0.000 

Events                    6348 
Total time at risk         40524 
Max. log. likelihood      -9801.5 
LR test statistic         10007.71 
Degrees of freedom        2 
Overall p-value           0
```

If instead, I simulate the covariates from a normal distribution, then I get the expected results:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(survival)
library(flexsurv)

n <- 10000
# Covariates
set.seed(123)
x <- cbind(rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
cens <- 5
# Survival times
set.seed(123)
sim <- rweibull(n, scale = 5, shape = 3)
status <- ifelse(sim < cens, 1, 0)
sim <- ifelse(sim < cens, sim, cens)

hist(sim)
mean(status)


# Estimated parameters


phreg(Surv(sim, status) ~ x[,1] + x[,2],
      dist = "weibull")
```

**Results:**

```
Call:
phreg(formula = Surv(sim, status) ~ x[, 1] + x[, 2], dist = "weibull")

Covariate          W.mean      Coef Exp(Coef)  se(Coef)    Wald p
x[, 1]             -0.004     0.001     1.001     0.013     0.914 
x[, 2]             -0.008     0.001     1.001     0.013     0.942 

log(scale)                    1.608               0.004     0.000 
log(shape)                    1.123               0.011     0.000 

Events                    6348 
Total time at risk         40524 
Max. log. likelihood      -14805 
LR test statistic         0.02 
Degrees of freedom        2 
Overall p-value           0.991628
```

## Question.

**Why is this happening?** I thought one could fit a proportional hazards Weibull model with binary covariates.